# Sequential number field for each user in a common table

Tags: php, mysql, sequential

I have a user table and a goals table. Users can enter goals. Each table has an `INT` primary key that is auto incremented. Now I would like to add an `INT` field to the goals table that represents the users' goal ID such that if UserA enters 5 goals this new field will contain the values from 1 to 5. The same is true for UserB .. UserN. Can I do this on the MySQL side alone or do I have to pull the data out beforehand in my PHP code to determine the next number.

Comment: how do you know how many goals a user have?, in other words, how do you get the goals of each users?

Comment: There is a foreign key in the goals table that references the userID

Comment: try with an update table users using a select with a inner join, without the table structure or some code it's like a blind help.

Answer (score 0):

What about a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO goals(col1, col2, col3, user_goal_id) 
  SELECT :val1, :val2, :val3, MAX(user_goal_id)+1 
  FROM goals 
  WHERE user_id = :user_id 
  GROUP BY user_id
```

? I guess this is the easiest way...

Or maybe this could also work:

```
INSERT INTO goals(col1, col2, col3, user_goal_id) 
  SELECT :val1, :val2, :val3, user_goal_id+1 
  FROM goals 
  WHERE user_id = :user_id 
  ORDER BY user_goal_id DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Or You can create a TRIGGER or some FUNCTION...

Comment: Do you have an example for a Trigger?

Comment: Actually never mind my request for a trigger example, my hosting provider doesn't support them.

Comment: Just found out this does not work: [you can't insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html). Seems like the easiest thing to do would be in code. First get the highest ID then send the insert statement with the ID incremented.

Comment: Why shouldn't you insert a selected values? The link You have posted says it is possible and I am using it quite often - just like in the example above in my answer...